# How is this question "too broad" and how can it be made more specific?

Tags: discussion

[Web app to immediately look up number of electrons?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100523/web-app-to-immediately-look-up-number-of-electrons)

Comment: There can be more than one reason a question is closed. Some choose the best fit/obvious, I choose the most likely to be a permanent problem. It varies but If the question doesn't meet our standards after editing it won't be reopened even though the reason it was closed is now fixed.

Comment: @A.K. you were one of the close-voters on this question, so can you explain why you did that? Martin's comment says to choose "too broad if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers". In this case the question cannot be answered by an entire book, and does not seem to have "many valid answers". I'm sure there's other reasons to close things as "too broad" but why did you do it in this case?

Answer (score 4):

I voted to close the question (along with others). I feel that it should remain closed for the following reasons:

- This is a borderline homework-like question that can be investigated by you and an Internet search engine; and
- There are multiple resources available that fit the bill or come close, which then turns your question into a request for a list, which goes against site policy.

The second point is, for me, the one that argues most closely for the "too broad" categorization.

Comment: Actually your second point argues already for being too broad: *too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format*; On the other hand, I do not share your concern in point three. If you know the exact sum formula, you know the total number of electrons, isomers won't change any of that.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - Amended per your (correct) comment.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt: "which then turns your question into a request for a list, which goes against site policy" do you care to list some of these or are you just saying something that is not actually true?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt what policy would you be in violation of, for listing them in a comment on this answer to a Meta question?

Comment: "There are multiple resources available that fit the bill or come close" ~ I believe this is false and deceiving. For the second part: something that "comes close" is not an answer to the question. For the first part: can you name one example of a resource that fits the bill? the question is no longer visible to you because you don't have 10k rep, but  the title is self-explanatory. Can you name one example of a web app that gives the number of electrons in a molecule, just by typing in the molecule's formula?